# How can I change a PWM wave voltage levels?

Tags: microcontroller, pwm

We have a PWM wave between 0V and 5V. It should be between 0V to 1.8V.  How can I do that?

Comment: A clarification: Are you trying to change a PWM waveform so that its swing is 0v to 1.8v, or that the value of its *modulated signal* now ranges from 0v to 1.8v, while the PWM wave still maintains a 5v swing? The former is rather easy - any sufficiently fast level shifter would do, or even a voltage divider if loading effects are not a concern, while the latter is much more difficult.

Comment: Thanks. Which Level Shifter IC do you recommend?

Comment: It depends on your frequency. It could also very well just be a voltage divider if the load is high-impedance (e.g. a MOS input)

Comment: Thanks again. The signal applied through a MOSFET gate. In the particular application of my circuit, the frequency is very low.

Comment: Please help me on this matter. How can I convert 5v (Logic 1) to 1.8v (Logic 1)?

Comment: Quick search yields [all of these](https://www.ti.com/logic-circuit/voltage-level-translation/unidirectional-voltage-translation/products.html); a voltage divider could also work well enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the same resolution on the output as your PWM step size, reduce the 5V with a voltage divider to say 36% of 5V.

A level shifter is all you need or a gate that can tolerate 5V input with a dual supply or open drain pullup on the output.

If you wanted a DC average from 0 to 100% d.c.,  use a filter.

If you wanted a PWM to DC with a lower ripple and fast response time, use an inverting integrator with an NPO or metal film cap on a negative pulse with a S&H for voltage, then dump and wait for next pulse with a faster filter afterwards to reduce noise.

Using a Vref of 1.8V will eliminate error tolerance if any on the Vdd=5V.

Level shifters IC’s come in a wide variety of solutions.

For a level shifter using an R divider from CMOS to CMOS may have some overshoot from the Miller capacitance, but the load will also have some so if that was a concern, adding a small cap could match the impedance and thus eliminate the overshoot by an additional small pF added to the 36% divider.

[Ref my simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDCCMCmC0CcUwDoBMYyoOxYMxgA5UA2eeLEAVgkpFwKrkkgCgAzEVVAFim99QEGkflCjJaKVhy4CsqTkM7zw4yclYB3RcOIRBDdAzAttBqIJ0h4xcCwDGnHtdvmbqyMgzefvsDFhmEFh1DFZHcyMnAUIPLz8E-yZIEG5keAJKeUoCSHhILGJIIvB4rWi%20AWcokzNq2NllBVqrKMjKWxMIpVx0Ct6ICE9EhICggmQsbkLcQu5USgXuLLhSUrDTVqVzAbsAJSt3c25jVW4aVUGJFgBzK12d4lOTACcKo%20cRXhoWN8bsBSNXY-P7bWK4RacWIQYjnX50SFRCGAjqqXB6W4IlG2ZFNS4sc64VInKDwBRZVyoobEAD6sJpYBp3Ah3BpqAkDI0DLZNOKNNwLAO-1iBH0sRSCkgfk4EhlklKrEJqWElgKtjyzVJdNZjJOU15jKk3NQvPg-IJYCJ%20F4kEszMlZNUBG13OZlFZUs5kGNNOdAsc530qMDUNOwxGvjGKUCk3gJyKqDj8Et3GKnTKm1xC1sIezdm0WdiuehLCAA). This is the most trivial solution with a CMOS driver shown as a discrete FET (your source ?)